# List all item from taskbar

Tags: vb.net

I want to list all item in a windows Taskbar. Not the process name.

```
    For Each processname As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If processname.MainWindowTitle <> "" Then ListBox1.Items.Add(processname.MainWindowTitle)
    Next
```

The above code list only the running application name. but i want to list all item including directory and drives as well.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find all Windows 7 pinned applications?

Answer (score 0):

To get the path of the executable from a process, use the [Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.modules.aspx) property.
The [ProcessModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule.aspx) class has a [FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule.filename.aspx) property which contains the path you're looking for.

---

**Example:**

```
For Each processname As Process In Process.GetProcesses
    If processname.MainWindowTitle <> "" Then 
        Console.WriteLine(processname.MainWindowTitle)
        Try
            ' catch win32expection if rights are missing
            Console.WriteLine("--> " & processname.Modules(0).FileName)
        Catch 
        End Try
    End if
Next
```

**Output:**

> ...
>   LINQPad 4
>   --> C:\Tools\LINQPad.exe
>   vb.net - List all item from taskbar - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome
>   --> C:\Users\theuser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>   ...